# What's the difference between Raspberry 3B+ and Element14 version?

Tags: pi-3b+

I've just received a message from an Aliexpress seller, and they told me they are out of 3B+ model stock, but that they could send me a "Element14 version".

What is that version? I can't find an accurate answer, It looks like that version is made by another manufacturer.

Comment: Sounds like BS - buy from a reputable reseller.

Comment: As per tlfong's answer there are a few top level distributors of the Pi, one of which is Element14, who have been with them since the beginning.  So on the one hand this would be a good thing *except* that there is no "Element14" model.  Either it is a 3B+ or else it is some other model, calling it an "Element14 version" is a bit like a waiter saying, "Sorry, we are all out of the fish special but we still have elephants on parade".  May sound cool but in context it is nonsensical.  If someone pitches you a non-sequitur, don't give them any money ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

Rpi3B+ from AliExpress OK?

***Answer***

Yes, should be OK, except perhaps a little bit more expensive.

A couple of years ago, an old version of Rpi was manufactured in ShenZhen, China. And the PCB colour is red (China Red!).  Now all Rpi's are manufactured in Sony Wales, UK, so I have heard.

These years I used to buy Rpi's from RS and E14 Hong Kong, shipped from UK via Singapore, and found no problem.  Last year I bought a couple of RpiZs and RpiZWs from one of the authorized Rpi resellers in China.  It is a TaoBao (AliExpress) shop in Shanghai. Again I found no problem, same price (converted to RMB), same versions of Rpi.

I bought the Rpi's from an authorized TaoBao/AliExpress reseller in China, and not from other non-authorized shops, because those fake shops often buy the goods from UK or US, or from eBay (when everybody can buy one only), say, and then resell it, marking up price 30% or more, so it is not worth it, except to those rich guys with too much money to spend.  I think it is legal, except there might be a warranty problem

***I think it is very very unlikely that there is another Made in China version of Rpi.***

*BTW, Rpi3B+ out of stock may be a good news, implying that Rp4 is coming to town! :)*

***References***

[Differences between Raspberry Pi B, B+, A+, 2B, 3B - Jarvan, Elecrow 2017dec21](https://www.elecrow.com/blog/differences-between-raspberry-pi-b-b-a-2b-3b/)

[image: made in china rpi]

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Eben Upton has said in an interview earlier this year there is no chance the Pi 4 will be here until 2020.  https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-everything-we-know,38539.html

Comment: Yes, .. but I am a huge fan of BlueMoon Camera for years. Usually more than 6 months before the official release date, I can buy "early bird" fake models at 30% discount or so.  The early bird fake version is almost always the same as the real thing to come later, except there is is no warranty.  Usually the manufacturer wants the users to stress test out their new thing, to make sure that the battery won't explode in 40 degree C, not too many stupid newbies would damage the auto locking sd card socket etc etc.  Then they might make improvements and perhaps also postpone the release date:) ,